# .html() on a div that deletes itself

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome

I'm experiencing an issue with the .html() function called on a div. I have a jQuery Dialog which contains a div with a select option input. On the change event of the select option input, an ajax call is done to a java servlet which produces new code to be put in the div with .html(). Here is the "success" function of my ajax call:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        alert($('#myDivId').html());
        $('#myDivId').empty().html(data);
        alert($('#myDivId').html());
    }
}
```

Here is the fun part! The first time I change the select value, it works very well. When I try again, the ajax call works as expected, but what's on the screen (chrome and IE) doesn't reflect what's returned by the html() function. After the first time it called, the alert shows, say:

```
<b>Hello</b>
```

Before the html() call, then after it says:

```
<b>World</b>
```

But the Div on chrome and IE still shows **Hello**.

Any clue?

Comment: you don't need `.empty()`

Comment: Press OK on the alert, it should then update to `World`. This is a symptom of actions that block code execution, such as alert, confirm, prompt, and synchronous ajax requests.

Comment: Are you sure that `$('#myDivId')` is what you are looking at?

Comment: @mikakun If i recall right there were $#html()-without-$#empty() related memory leaks in some browsers at some point. #bettersafethansorry

Comment: @Flo not aware of that; can you point to any article describing this ?

Comment: @mikakun Not right now, no. Can't seen to find anything on the first 2-3 Google pages. Must've been in early 1.x times and oldIE anyway, so probably not too relevant nowadays. Just a habit I picked up.

Comment: Thx to you all. @mikakun: I know I don't need .empty(), but I put it there to see if it helps.

Comment: @freakish: Yes, I'm pretty sure as it works once. If I inspect the div with chrome, I see the old code, not the new, even though the .html() function returns the new.

Comment: @Kevin B: In the real code, I don't put the alert and it still doesn't work

Comment: maybe you have some problems accessing that result, did you look into the result with firebug,chrom-inspector etc if your response is what it should look like? i do know that developing on localhost is often pruned with "no access" or other exceptions, uploaded to a real webserver it works like a charm :)

Do you have a working example on jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem here. The div pb-div was dynamically created. In a specific case of my application, that div gets removed from the page. When it's re-created using the same script, it looks like the browse still has an handle on the other div or something like that. I simply added the timestamp in the DIV name to always have a unique ID and it worked!